# how to create a SPWorkflowTemplate

Tags: workflow

I am trying to add a custom workflow to the WorkflowTemplates library of my web. So how does one go about creating a new `SPWorkflowTemplate` object and adding it to the WorkflowTemplates collection of the SPWeb object? I can only find information on associating these with lists/webs/content types

Comment: What is the goal of creating a new SPWorkflowTemplate? What is that you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm simply trying to get familiar with the object model. my original reason was to manually add a k2 workflow that didn't want to be added the normal way (there was no option to set the workflow history and workflow tasks lists)